# Find triplets (a, b ,c) in an array such that a + b + c = 0

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to find all distinct triplets (a, b, c) in an array such that a + b + c = 0.

I implemented the algorithm in java but I am getting TLE when the input is large (for example 100,000 zeroes, etc).

For 100,000 zeroes, it should output (0, 0, 0) only.

Can someone give some idea about how to speed this up?

Below is the function which I have written. It takes an array as input and returns all unique triplets having the desired property as a list.

```
public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        List<List<Integer>> ll = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++){
            int x = nums[i];
            int start = i + 1;
            int end = nums.length - 1;
            int sum = -x;
            while(start < end){
                int y = nums[start] + nums[end];
                if(y == sum){
                    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    list.add(nums[start]);
                    list.add(nums[end]);
                    list.add(x);
                    Collections.sort(list);
                    ll.add(list);
                }
                if(y < sum)
                    start++;
                else
                    end--;
            }
        }
        return ll.stream()
                 .distinct()
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: When you have to add three numbers to make zero, either all three numbers are zero; or one is zero, and the other two are equal in magnitude but opposite signs; or two are positive and one is negative and equal to minus the sum of the positives; or two are negative and one is positive and equal to minus the sum of the negatives. Basically, you've got three "pools" of numbers (negative, zero, positive) that could be treated separately.

Comment: Use a `HashSet` instead of `ll.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: HINT: If `a + b + c = 0`, then `a + b` *must* equal `-c`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch this is exactly what i have implemented.

Comment: After sorting `nums`, I would remove duplicates so that 0 appears at most three times, and every other number appears at most two times. So the 100,000 zeros end up being 3 zeros.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp: Great point. I never get why people use streams for doing very simple things

Comment: @chelsea: No you have not implemented what Elliot Frisch hinted. Check my answer

Comment: So your input array should infact be a set (ie. no duplicates) however multiple (in this particular case twice or thrice if 0) use of each element is allowed. This is essential because those duplicates will eventually generate duplicate results if they can be complemented by a negative value. So this reduces the problem to a little convoluted version of the coin change problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is nothing you can do about the time complexity. Two indices must explore the array independently (except for starting/ending points), while the third can be constrained, like in your algorithm, which means that the complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>). This dominates the preliminary sorting of the array, which is O(n·log(n)), and also a “demultiplication” step, which is O(n).

I wrote “demultiplication” because a “deduplication” is not desirable: suppose the array is `[-1,-1,0,2]`. Deduplicating it would eliminate the only solution. But a solution can't contain an integer more than twice, unless it's `0`, in which case `[0,0,0]` is a solution. All integers appearing more than twice, or thrice in the case of `0`, are redundant and can be eliminated in one pass after sorting and before the main algorithm.

As for the factor, it could be improved by limiting the exploration to what makes sense. I would modify your algorithm by making the pair of indices that you move until they meet, start outwards from where they meet, until the lower one hits the major index, or the upper one hits the end of the array. The starting point of the scan can be remembered across scans, adjusting it downwards as the major index moves upwards. If the starting point (actually a starting pair of adjacent indices) is outside the current range, the scan can be omitted tout court. Finding the initial starting point is an additional part of the algorithm which, after sorting, could be O(log(n)), but a very simple O(n) version would do just as well.

I have no time now to translate all the above into Java code, sorry. All I can do now is jot down the “demultiplication” code (untested) that goes right after the sorting of the array:

```
int len = 1;
int last = nums[0];
int count = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    int x = nums[i];
    if (x != last) {
        nums[len++] = x;
        last = x;
        count = 1;
    } else if (count < 2 || x == 0 && count < 3) {
        nums[len++] = x;
        count++;
    }
}
// use len instead of nums.length from this point on
```

Answer (score 1):

The big time component I see, is that for the 100,000 zeroes example, you will hitting the if (y == sum) block for **every single possible case**. This appears to be the worst case for performance since you will never skip that block.

The largest improvement I can see is to first **de-duplicate your input**. Unfortunately sets won't work as we need still maintain up to three of the same entry. Thus, my recommendation is, after your sort, to loop through the input array and whenever you encounter more than three copies of a number in a row, remove the extras. They are not needed for the problem and just waste time.

Comment: Suppose the array is `[-1, -1, 0, 2]`. Eliminating all duplicates eliminates the only solution here.

Comment: @WalterTross I may have poorly communicated my solution. I suggested de-duplicating and making two copies. That will still work for your input. However, I do see a problem I need to correct. If the input is only [-1, 0, 2], my current TreeSet-based solution will output (-1, -1, 2) even though there is only one -1. I'm going to revise my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [List](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/98au/java/jdk1.2beta4/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (an implementation of that is [ArrayList](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp)) to store the combinations you already had. Always store a new value in the format of

```
a,b,c
```

where **a <= b <= c**

so, whenever you get a combination which may or may not already have been found, generate a `String` in the same format and check whether it is present in your `List`. If so, then do not `add` it. Otherwise `add` it to your `List`. After this you could convert the found values into numeric values. If you want to quicken it up, you could create a `class` like:

```
class XYZ {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    public XYZ(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public isMatch(int x, int y, int z) {
        return (this.x == x) &&
               (this.y == y) &&
               (this.z == z);
    }

    public static boolean anyMatch(List<XYZ> list, int x, int y, int z) {
        for (XYZ xyz : list) {
            if (xyz.isMatch(x, y, z)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void addIfNotExists(List<XYZ> list, int x, int y, int z) {
        if (!anyMatch(list, x, y, z)) list.add(new XYZ(x, y, z));
    }
}
```

and you could use this class for your purpose, just make sure that **x <= y <= z**.

Answer (score 0):

The filtering of non-unique triplets at the end can be eliminated by using a hash-table that stores the triplets in a sorted order, so all combinations of a triplet (with different ordering) gets stored exactly once.

Use a hashmap/hashset instead of an arraylist.

```
HashSet<List<Integer>> ll = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();
    .   .   .
    list.addAll(a,b,c)
    Collections.sort(list)
    ll.add(list)
```

In addition to this, You could also use another lookup table to ensure each repeating item in nums[] is used to calculate the triplets only once.

```
lookup_table = HashMap();
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++){
    // we have already found triplets starting from nums[i]
    // eg. [-1,-1,0,1], we don't need to calculate
    // the same triplets for the second '-1'. 
    if (lookup_table.contains(nums[i]))
        continue;

    // Mark nums[i] as 'solved'
    lookup_table.add(nums[i])

    // usual processing here
    int x = nums[i];
```

Or, since your nums[] list is already sorted, you could just skip repeating items, doing away the need for another lookup table.

```
i = 0;
while (i < nums.length - 1){
    // we have already found triplets starting from nums[i]
    // eg. [-1,-1,0,1], we don't need to calculate
    // the same triplets for the second '-1'.
    x = nums[i];

    // skip repeating items
    while (x == nums[i++]);

    // usual processing here
    .  .  .
    i++;
 }
```

and then you could just return the hashset as a list at the end.